# Every program I build with dmd crashes with a segfault

Tags: segmentation-fault, d

Every single D program that I compile with `dmd` crashes with a segfault when I to run them.

I stripped more and more out of the program I was writing to get the smallest program that does this and this

```
void main() {}
```

will crash with a segfault.

I have not used D or dmd in a few weeks, but it was working fine last I noticed. I have not upgraded or changed dmd in that time, and can not think of any other change or update that might have affected dmd.

Since finding that this was happening with dmd, I have re-installed the operating system and all the software and the same behaviour persists.

I have tried building dmd from source but the first thing it does is run a `../generated/build` program, but that is a D program so it crashes.

It also happens if I `dub init` a new project, `dub build` it and run the output. It is not just calling using dmd alone that produces executables that crash.

I have tried reverting to former versions of dmd, versions that I am pretty sure that I have used successfully before, and programs built with them also crash now where they did not crash before.

The Linux distribution is lxle, but /etc/os-release identifies the system as Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Any help or ideas about what is causing this behaviour, and how to fix it, would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit**

`ldd` shows

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xb7f4b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7e7c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb7e72000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7e54000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7c78000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7f4d000)
```

I have no idea if that is typical, but the files listed there exist, or are symlinks to files that exist.

`break main` and `run` in `gdb` gives

```
Starting program: /home/ant/dtest/dtest 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00448865 in _D2rt19sections_elf_shared10_tlsRangesFNbNcNdNiZSQBv4util9container5array__T5ArrayTAvZQk ()
```

but I don't know what to do with that information.

**Further edit**

Adding `--DRT-gcopts="parallel:0"` to the `dmd` command line made no difference to the program's behaviour. The generated program still crashes with a seg fault (and a claim that the core was dumped but no noticeable coredump file).

Comment: What happens when you compile with ldc?

Comment: Ldc only have linux 64-bit pre-compiled binaries, and I need 32-bit. I will try gdc (they have 32 bit binaries) first, and then try compiling one of them from source again.

Comment: Gdc appears to work perfectly. I guess I don't need to know what happened with dmd or why it failed me, or why completely re-installing the OS and all the software didn't fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe the OS reinstall included a d library package that conflicts with the other thing you installed. i know it sounds far fetched but... maybe.

i'd try `ldd program_generated_by_dmd` and see what it shows, then also `dmd -g plain_main.d` and `gdb ./plain_main` and see if the debugger tells you anything about the crsh.

Comment: Can you try running with `--DRT-gcopts="parallel:0"` to see if it helps in any way?
Alternatively you can put the following in any module included: `static if (__VERSION__ >= 2087) extern(C) __gshared string[] rt_options = [ "gcopt=parallel:0" ];`